# ffmpeg - cannot find matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_amix_0

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp4 and I am trying to merge multiple audio files into it. The command is generated dynamically given the number of audio and their offset. Everything works when I have multiple audios to merge but doesn't when I have one audio file to merge.

Here is the command to merge single audio into the mp4

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./video.mp4  -itsoffset 00:00:1.753 -i ./audio0.mp3  -filter_complex amix -map 0:v  -map 1:a  -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac -strict experimental -t 10 ./finalVideo.mp4
```

Here is the command to merge multiple audio files which works

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./video.mp4  -itsoffset 00:00:1.753 -i ./audio0.mp3  -itsoffset 00:00:0.113 -i ./audio/audio1.mp3  -filter_complex amix -map 0:v  -map 1:a  -map 2:a  -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac -strict experimental -t 10 ./finalVideo.mp4
```

Comment: Share full log of non-working command.